# Adding titles to sorted nodes in a View

Tags: views

So I'm struggling again with my sorted links: there are many many links (node type) which also contain the field "link_category".

I collect them all in a view and sort them by "link_category".

It works like a charm and looks like this:

```
link 1 | Category 1
link 2 | Category 1
link 3 | Category 1
link 1 | Category 2
link 2 | Category 2
link 3 | Category 2
link 4 | Category 2
link 1 | Category 3
link 2 | Category 3
link 3 | Category 3
```

but now I want to hide the link_category on each item and instead, show one title above them like:

```
*Category 1:

link 1
link 2
link 3

*Category 2:

link 1
link 2
link 3
link 4

*Category 3:

link 1
link 2
link 3
```

Is it somehow possible with Views or do I need some extra modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the group by field option.

The process would go as follows.

In Fromt section next to the Format you have settings click on that.

[image]

You will find **Grouping field Nr.1** Select the category Field from the list.

[image]

This would group the fields with the Category. But Now you would see both category as well as Link. Now you can go to the Category field settings and select exclude from Display so that only the links would be shown.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! One more question: how can I format the category title? I can't find any CSS options for it…

Comment: what kind of ccs options do you need?

Comment: Oh I got it, sorry. : ) I can access the element via CSS by using ".view-viewname caption"!